# How to plot this implicit function?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

The command

```
ContourPlot[{RealAbs[x + 1/y] + RealAbs[10/3 - x + y] == 
10/3 + y + 1/y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

, as one sees, draws abstraction in blue. With the options

```
ContourPlot[{RealAbs[x + 1/y] + RealAbs[10/3 - x + y] == 
10/3 + y + 1/y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 300, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

one obtains an empty plot.
The command

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[RealAbs[x + 1/y] + RealAbs[10/3 - x + y] == 10/3 + 1/y + y, {x, y}],
PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]
```

> `Region[Embedding dimension: 2]`

fails too.
Just to compare, see the result of the the command of Maple 2021

```
plots:-implicitplot (abs (x + 1/y) + abs (x + 1/y) = 10/3 + y + 1/y, x = -5 .. 5, y = -5 .. 5);
```

[image]

I think this is not only a graphics problem. Let us consider

```
Reduce[{RealAbs[x + 1/y] + RealAbs[10/3 - x + y] == 10/3 + y + 1/y}, x, Reals]
```

> `(y == -3 &&  x == 1/3) || (-3 < y < -(1/3) && -(1/y) <= x <=  1/3 (10 + 3 y)) || (y == -(1/3) &&  x == 3) || (y > 0 && -(1/y) <= x <= 1/3 (10 + 3 y))`

and the  result in Maple of

```
solve (abs (x + 1/y) + abs (x + 1/y) = 10/3 + y + 1/y, x);
```

> `piecewise (y < -3, [], y = -3, [1/3],  y < -1/3, [(3*y^2 + 10*y - 3)/(6*y), (-3*y^2 - 10*y - 9)/(6*y)],  y = -1/3, [3], y <= 0, [],  0 < y, [(3*y^2 + 10*y - 3)/(6*y), (-3*y^2 - 10*y - 9)/(6*y)])`

The latter is in accordance with the plot done in Maple, whereas the former does not seem true.

Is there a way to plot the implicit function under consideration in Mathematica?

PS. Sorry for the poor question. My incorrect Maple code misled me (This is explanation, but not justification.).

Comment: `Simplify[RealAbs[x + 1/y] + RealAbs[10/3 - x + y] == 10/3 + y + 1/y , 
 1/4 <= x <= 22/3 && y == 4]`  is  `True`. It means that the picture contain the segment `Line[{1/4,4},{22/3,4}]`

Comment: Please don't use the `bugs` tag unless it's confirmed.

Comment: @gwr: I submitted it few years ago.

Comment: BTW, `Region[ImplicitRegion[
  RealAbs[x + 1/y] + RealAbs[10/3 - x + y] == 10/3 + 1/y + y && 
   x >= -5 && x <= 5 && y >= -5 && y <= 5, {x, y}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]` should to work, but  the command doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to visualize the relation
$$
|f(x,y)| + |g(x,y)| = f(x,y) + g(x,y)
$$
where $f(x,y) = x+1/y$ and $g(x,y) = \frac{10}{3} - x + y$.  In the above form, it is fairly evident that this relation is satisfied if and only if $f(x,y) \geq 0$ and $g(x,y) \geq 0$.  In other words, this equation does not define a *contour*;  it defines a *region*:

```
RegionPlot[{Abs[x + 1/y] + Abs[10/3 - x + y] == 10/3 + y + 1/y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Increasing the value of `PlotPoints` leads to better definition of the "corners" at $(-3,\frac13)$ and $(-\frac13,3)$, and also reduces the length of the spurious "stem" along the positive $x$-axis.

Knowing this, it appears that the Mathematica output you provide from `Reduce` (which involves allowed ranges of `x` for each `y` value) is correct.  The fact that Maple outputs a 1-D curve when using `plots` is highly misleading;  and the output of `solve` is correct only if (for example)

```
[(3*y^2 + 10*y - 3)/(6*y), (-3*y^2 - 10*y - 9)/(6*y)]
```

stands for the interval between these two endpoints.  (I am not familiar enough with Maple syntax to know whether the above output stands only for two distinct points, or whether it implicitly includes the interval between them as well.)

Comment: Are you serious? Could you ground your '"You are trying to visualize the relation..." ?  TIA. Hope you understand this is not it. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @user64494:  My point is that the equation you are plotting, which can be written as $$\left|x + \frac{1}{y}\right| + \left| \frac{10}{3} - x + y \right| = \left( x + \frac{1}{y} \right) + \left( \frac{10}{3} - x + y \right)$$does not define a set of curves;  it defines a 2-D region of the plane.  As such, `RegionPlot` is more appropriate.  `ContourPlot` is finding that points in the interior of this region also satisfy the equation, which is why it tries to fill in the region with lines. ...

Comment: That said, I'm a bit taken aback by your comment;  if this doesn't answer your question then I've definitely misunderstood it.  Can you elaborate on what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you. I got it. My Maple code was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: (under Possible Issues)

> Contours f(x,y)==0 for functions where f(x,y)>=0 are always poorly
> detected

```
f[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ] := 
 Boole[RealAbs[x + 1/y] + RealAbs[10/3 - x + y] == 10/3 + y + 1/y]
```

> Giving a value in between allows for easy contouring:

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0.5, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is a plot of `Boole[RealAbs[x + 1/y] + RealAbs[10/3 - x + y] == 10/3 + y + 1/y]==0.5`, not the required plot. I also don't understand how `Boole` can take `0.5`.  Could you explain it? TIA.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see any explanation of work `Boole[RealAbs[x + 1/y] + RealAbs[10/3 - x + y] == 10/3 + y + 1/y]==0.5`.

Comment: This is a wrong answer. I don't understand upvotes for it.

Comment: @user64494  Obviously you didn't get this answer: How can you state it "wrong"?